# SimpleUserWrongPassword('Old password is invalid');

Tags: fuelphp

Old password invalid
I've been working this one for week

How to make this one work

```
public function action_edit($id = null)
{
    $user = Model_User::find($id);
    //$val = Model_User::validate('edit');

    // if ($val->run())
    // {
```

//simple auth update user

```
        $user = Auth::update_user(
                    array(
                        'email'        => Input::post('email'), 
                        'password'     => Input::post('password'),    
                        'old_password' => Input::post('oldpassword'),
                    )
                );

        if ($user)
        {
            Session::set_flash('success', e('Updated user #' ));

            Response::redirect('admin/users');
        }
    else
    {
        if (Input::method() == 'POST')
        {
            $user = Auth::update_user(
                    array(
                        'email'        => $val->validated('email'), 
                        'password'     => $val->validated('password'),    
                        'old_password' => $val->validated('oldpassword'),
                    )
                );
            Session::set_flash('error', $val->error());
        }

        $this->template->set_global('user', $user, false);
    }

    $this->template->title = "Users";
    $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/users/edit');

}
```

Heres my code in controller function edit
Old password is invalid

Comment: Auth::update_user(
    array(
        'email'        => 'anewemail@example.org',  // set a new email address
        'password'     => 'thisismynewpassword',    // set a new password
        'old_password' => 'thisismysecretpassword', // to do so, give the current one!
        'phone'        => '+1 (555) 123-1212',     // and add the phone number to the metadata
    )
);  Here's the code I was trying to use